# C# WPF AvalonDock loses data binding after reloading layout

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, avalondock

I'm working with avalon-dock plugin and found a super annoying problem. My application uses data-binding in xamls. I tried to save the layout of avalon-dock when the application exits, and load the layout when the app start again(Using XmlLayoutSerializer.Deserialize() & Serialize()). The layout is saved and retrived perfectly.

But all the data-bindings are destroyed, that is, the content of the binded property stays the same as when the application last exits, but data-binding NO LONGER WORKS. Seems avalon-dock deserialize process destroyed the data-binding and the contents are sticked to a permanant value.

I tried to look for ways of setting what kind of layout data for avalon-dock to save & retrive but nothing found. Could any body solve the problem or provide some hints of workarounds?

Thanks.

Here's what the binding likes(Here the title is binded):

```
<avalon:LayoutAnchorable ContentId="Basic_Docu" 
CanHide="False" 
CanClose="False"
Title ="{Binding MainPageText.Basic_Tab_Title, Source={StaticResource R}}">
  <Frame Name="Basic_Docu_Frame">
  </Frame>
</avalon:LayoutAnchorable>
```

Here's the codes saving and retriving the layouts:

```
void Save_LayoutInfo()
{
    try
    {
        string Working_Dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\layout";
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Working_Dir);
        XmlLayoutSerializer layoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(dockingManager);
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Working_Dir + "\\" + "MainPage"))
        {
            layoutSerializer.Serialize(writer);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ;
    }
}

void Retrive_LayoutInfo()
{
    try
    {
        string Working_Dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\layout";
        XmlLayoutSerializer layoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(dockingManager);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Working_Dir + "\\" + "MainPage"))
        {
            layoutSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LayoutItemContainerStyleSlector` in 'XAML' to maintain the binding.

for example:

```
    <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
        <pane:PanesStyleSelector>
            <pane:PanesStyleSelector.ToolStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutAnchorableItem}">                        
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Model.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}}" />
                    <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}" />
                    <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="RightToLeft" />
                    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                </Style>
            </pane:PanesStyleSelector.ToolStyle>
            <pane:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcad:LayoutItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                    <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}" />
                    <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Model.CanClose}" />
                    <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}" />
                    <Setter Property="CanFloat" Value="{Binding Model.CanFloat}" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                </Style>
            </pane:PanesStyleSelector.FileStyle>
        </pane:PanesStyleSelector>
    </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyleSelector>
```